# Saving properties into a file are interpreted by store method

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties, fileoutputstream

I have a properties file 1, which after ordering it and eliminating duplicates, I save it in a new properties file 2. My problem is that when saving my properties, the store method is interpreting the text of my property and saves it interpreted, not as it is.

This is my method:

```
void saveProperties(Properties properties) {
   File file = new File("C:\\Files\\new.properties");
   FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
   properties.store(fileOutputStream, "Properties");
}
```

This is my store method Override, so it doesn't add escape characters:

```
public void store(OutputStream out, Properties properties) throws IOException {
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out, "8859_1"));
    bw.write("#" + new Date().toString());
    bw.newLine();
    synchronized (this) {
        for (Enumeration e = properties.keys(); e.hasMoreElements();) {
            String key = (String) e.nextElement();
            String val = (String) properties.get(key);
            // Commented out to stop '/' or ':' or '#' chars being replaced
            // key = saveConvert(key, true, escUnicode);
            // val = saveConvert(val, false, escUnicode);
            bw.write(key + "=" + val);
            bw.newLine();
        }
    }
    bw.flush();
}
```

These are my two test properties.:

```
myPropertieTest1=Sure?\\nplease click \\'here\\' to see more info.
myPropertieTest2=Requirements\:<br/>\n" + "name, surname, address.
```

And this is the result saved in my new properties file:

```
mypropertietest1=Sure?\nplease click \'here\' to see more info.
mypropertietest2=Requirements:<br/>
" + "name, surname, address.
```

The escape characters disappear, even in Test2 the property is saved in two lines because the line breaks are interpreted.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you are loading the properties value, but when I tried it on local it works without this issue:

```
public class Demo{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Demo demo = new Demo();
        FileReader reader = new FileReader("old.properties");
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.load(reader);
        demo.saveProperties(prop);
    }

    void saveProperties(Properties properties) throws IOException {
        File file = new File("new.properties");
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        properties.store(fileOutputStream, "Properties");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @tejas.bargal, my problem is that I'm using the method store that I posted, not the properties store method, that why is not working for me